# How jquery widgets keep track of the initial jquery object? (an event case scenario)

Tags: jquery-ui, widget, singleton, jquery

I'll try to be as simple as I can be:

I wrote a jquery widget with the help of **jqueryui** (go to themeroller, download a theme, unzip it and there at the `development-bundle` folder you'll find a folder called `ui`, then include only the `jquery.ui.widget.js` for this example to run):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>jQuery widget construction & Events</title>
<style>
  h1 {
     color: #808080;
  }
  h1:hover {
     color: #000000;
     text-decoration: none;
     cursor: pointer;
  }
  a {
     color: #808080;
     background-color: #CCFF33;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Click Me</h1>

<div class=content>
<p>
<a href="http://speckyboy.com/2010/01/20/25-tutorials-and-resources-for-learning-jquery-ui/">spekyboy</a>
</p>
<p>
<a href="http://www.learningjquery.com/">learning jquery</a>
</p>    
</div>

<script src="../jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

<script>
////////////////////////Plugin Creation (Widget Factory)////////////////////////
///////////////////////////mycompany.linkLocation///////////////////////////////
(function( $ ) {
//1. use jQuery.widget() method, the Widget factory, to create plugins
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
$.widget( "mycompany.linkLocation", {
  //2. widget properties "foreground" and "background" (see docs)
  //-------------------------------------------------------------
  options: {
     color: "black",
     "background-color": "transparent",
     done: false,
     //3. a callback from the relevant widget event: linkLocation_onapply (see docs)
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     //where does this refers to (???)
     //evt refers to the custom jquery event object
     _onapply: function(evt, options){
        var attrs='';
        for(prop in this)
           attrs+=prop+', ';
        alert('from _onapply, this:\n'+attrs);
        attrs='';
        for(prop in evt)
           attrs+=prop+'='+evt[prop]+'\n';
        alert('from _onapply 1st arg, evt:\n'+attrs);
        //4. where is the reference to widget linkLocation for evt.target?
        //----------------------------------------------------------------
        $(evt.target).css(options);
     }
  },
  //5. used during construction by the Widget Factory (see docs)
  //------------------------------------------------------------
  //this refers to the object built by the Widget Factory
  _create: function() {
  },
  //6. used after initialization (see docs)
  //---------------------------------------
  //called as $("selector").widgetname("option", option_object)
  //or,
  //$("selector").widgetname("option", "key", "value")
  //this refers to the object built by the Widget Factory
   _setOption: function(key, value){
     this.options[ key ] = value;
  },
  //7. public method apply()
  //------------------------
  //this refers to the object built by the Widget Factory
  apply: function(evt){
     if(!this.options.done){
        //create a jquery object that wraps a specific dom element accessed
        //through the this.element provided by the Widget Factory
        var $this = $(this.element);
        this._css($this);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //8. maybe one reason we done all these: add memory and execute only once!//
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        this.options.done = true;
        //9. if apply() is called once then, _onapply() is called once
        //------------------------------------------------------------
        //event linkLocation_onapply will trigger method _onapply(), see docs
        this._trigger("_onapply", evt, {color: "white", "background-color": "purple"});
     }
  },
  //10. a private method _css()
  //--------------------------
  //this refers to the object built by the Widget Factory
  _css: function($elem){
     $elem.css({
        "background-color": this.options.background,
        "color": this.options.foreground
     });
  }
});
}( jQuery ));
//11. user overwites public property: this.options
//------------------------------------------------
//for the objects created by the Widget Factory
var options2 = {
   color: "blue",
   "background-color": "yellow"
};
//12. construct an object for every <a> element using the Widget Factory
$( "a" ).linkLocation(options2);
//13. call widget apply() methods
//-------------------------------
$('h1').on('click', function(evt) {
   //14. the jquery $(h1) object
   var attrs='';
   for(prop in this)
      attrs+=prop+', ';
   alert('From h1 tag onclick event, this:\n'+attrs);
   $( "a" ).linkLocation("apply").on("linklocation_onapply", 
      //15. never executed???
      function(evt, data){
         attrs='';
         for(prop in data)
            attrs+=prop+': '+data[prop]+'\n';
         alert('From linklocation_onapply event function, data:\n'+attrs);
      }
   );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

(please see my numbers in the code comments)
now, all we do is create ***(12)*** a widget with some options ***(2)***, that do nothing ***(5)***. User can change the default options during construction ***(11)***.
User can call public method `apply()` ***(7)*** to change anchor foreground-background colors based on widget options but we also wanted to define a callback that will be triggered on a custom jquery event ***(9)***.

Every time user clicks on h1 tag ***(13)*** method `apply()` ***(7)*** is executed from every widget called `linkLocation` and attached to anchor elements ***(12)***  BUT only once (we put code inside an if..else). As we said, method `apply()` changes anchor colors and triggers the callback function.

### My questions:

a) is `this` at callback `_onapply()` ***(3)*** the **jquery object that actually call my widget's public method** as we can see in the messages from comment ***(14)***?
The messages are:

```
From h1 tag onclick event, this:
jQuery17102845835909852654, align, click, focus, blur, title, lang, dir, dataset, 
itemScope, itemType, itemId, itemRef, itemProp, properties, itemValue, hidden, 
tabIndex, accessKey, ...
```

followed by our widget messages:

```
from _onapply, this:
jQuery17102845835909852654, toString, href, target, download, ping, rel, hreflang, 
type, text, coords, charset, name, rev, shape, protocol, host, hostname ...
```

and

```
from _onapply 1st arg, evt:
type=linklocation_onapply
timeStamp=1382545296011
jQuery17102845835909852654=true
...
```

if you compare you'll find that `_onapply` has extra properties-**why is this so**?

```
toString, href, target, download, ping, rel, hreflang, type, text, coords, charset,
name, rev, shape, protocol, host, hostname, port, pathname, search, hash
```

b) why is my event handler at comment ***(15)*** never been executed?

c) what's this always changing property `jQueryn` where n=number at the jquery object properties?
It seems that jquery isn't a singleton object and that seems to bahave bandly when we want to have memory on dom element statuses as in the case of the widget objects; they are stored in a jquery object but which one when it is constantly cloning itself?

and d) as you can see at comment ***(4)***, where is a reference to my widget `linkLocation` for the specific element that triggers my custom event?

Really, can't find the abstraction that the library promishes....keep on searching the source code for answers...
Thanks.

Comment: someone downvoted my question; can't see the reason! If you don't understand it might not be my fault.

Comment: at my question (a) it seems that I've catched a native browser element poluted with more functions cause of jquery (!)

Comment: If I have to catch the jquery object I should write instead below comment (14): var x = $( "a" ).linkLocation("apply") BUT not var x = $( "a" ).linkLocation("apply").data("linkLocation"); as the tutorial claims: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/ (!)

Comment: reading http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/ and I feel like my questions hit bull's eye here...

Answer (score 0):

After searching for answers I concluded to the following:

for Q.a) function `_onapply()` at widget's `options` changes execution context internally as it is asigned to the widget's connected element so, it's the element's reference

for Q.b) the event system implements the observable pattern; someone plays the role of been observed by others and that's the widget. An observable cannot respond to it's own signals (see comment ***(15)***) so, we need observers for this job i.e. attach event handlers to other elements for the specific events signaled by the widget and you have it, a respond by the observables (that's a new comment ***(16)*** with code).

What haven't been said or wrote is that we can have two types of observables in the widget construction: a formal one with the use of function `this.element.trigger(eventtype, data)`-a general trigger-and, a specific one that is called as `this._trigger(eventtype, event, data)` and is used to call functions attached to the widget AND to signal at the same time the observables-an options trigger!

Under comments ***(9)*** and ***(11)*** I implemented both types. What's strange with the `options trigger` is it's ability to call and signal where the event is named as `namespacewidgetname` with no connection dot or whatever.

An `options trigger` falls in two sub-categories according the position of the function that calls: 
- a `construction options trigger` that calls functions defined under construction
and
- a `user options trigger` that calls functions defined by the user and extend widget's semantics even if it's hard to understand it's usability as the developer can't predict user's extensions.

For Q.c) and Q.d) I feel unsafe to answer...

For my title question about the connection between the jquery object and the widget the answer is that there is none as widgets are tight to elements like the event system and jquery acts as an intermediate finding elements and attaching properties...

Let's test it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Custom Effect Methods</title>
<style>
  h1 {
     color: #808080;
  }
  h1:hover {
     color: #000000;
     text-decoration: none;
     cursor: pointer;
  }
  a {
     color: #808080;
     background-color: #CCFF33;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Click Me</h1>

<div class=content>
<p>
<a href="http://speckyboy.com/2010/01/20/25-tutorials-and-resources-for-learning-jquery-ui/">spekyboy</a>
</p>
<p>
<a href="http://www.learningjquery.com/">learning jquery</a>
</p>    
</div>

<script src="../jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>

<script>
////////////////////////Plugin Creation (Widget Factory)////////////////////////
///////////////////////////mycompany.linkLocation///////////////////////////////
(function($, window, document, undefined){
//1. use jQuery.widget() method, the Widget factory, to create plugins
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
$.widget( "mycompany.linkLocation", {
  //2. widget properties "foreground" and "background" (see docs)
  //-------------------------------------------------------------
  options: {
     that: this,
     color: "black",
     "background-color": "transparent",
     done: false,
     //3. a callback from the relevant widget event: linkLocation_onapply (see docs)
     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     //this refers to the element referencing the plugin (element.data property?)
     //evt refers to the custom jquery event object
     _onapply: function(evt, options){
        //4. where is the reference to widget linkLocation for evt.target?
        //----------------------------------------------------------------
        $(evt.target).css(options);
     }
  },
  //5. used during construction by the Widget Factory (see docs)
  //------------------------------------------------------------
  //this refers to the object built by the Widget Factory
  _create: function() {
  },
  //6. used after initialization (see docs)
  //---------------------------------------
  //called as $("selector").linkLocation("option", option_object)
  //or,
  //$("selector").linkLocation("option", "key", "value")
  //this refers to the object built by the Widget Factory
   _setOption: function(key, value){
     this.options[ key ] = value;
  },
  //7. public method apply()
  //------------------------
  //this refers to the object built by the Widget Factory
  apply: function(evt){
     if(!this.options.done){
        //create a jquery object that wraps a specific dom element accessed
        //through the this.element provided by the Widget Factory
        var $this = $(this.element);
        this._css($this);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //8. maybe one reason we done all these: add memory and execute only once!//
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        this.options.done = true;
        //9. if apply() main code is executed once then, 
        //onapply() & trigger are executed only once
        //------------------------------------------
        //(!!!construction options trigger!!!) register observers for event linkLocation_onapply
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        this._trigger("_onapply", evt, {color: "white", "background-color": "purple"});
        //(!!!user options trigger!!!) register observers for event linkLocation_onuserapply
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        this._trigger("_onuserapply", evt, {color: "white", "background-color": "orange"});
        //(!!!general trigger!!!) register observers for the event shown
        //---------------------------------------------------------------
        this.element.trigger("mycompany.linkLocation.customevent", this.options);
     }
  },
  //10. a private method _css()
  //--------------------------
  //this refers to the object built by the Widget Factory
  _css: function($elem){
     $elem.css({
        "background-color": this.options.background,
        "color": this.options.foreground
     });
  },
  _destroy: function() {
  }
});
}(jQuery, window, document));
//11. user overwites public property: this.options
//------------------------------------------------
//for the objects created by the Widget Factory
var options2 = {
   color: "blue",
   "background-color": "yellow",
   //a user supplied function that will trigger a custom event
   _onuserapply: function(evt, options){
      $(evt.target).css(options);
   }
};
//12. construct an object for every <a> element using the Widget Factory
var widgets = $( "a" ).linkLocation(options2);
//13. call widget apply() methods
//-------------------------------
$('h1').on('click', function(evt){
   //14. at this point this refers to h1 element
   //...
   $( "a" ).linkLocation("apply").on("linklocation_onapply", 
      //15. an observable cannot catch it's own signals!!!
      function(evt, data){
         attrs='';
         for(prop in data)
            attrs+=prop+': '+data[prop]+'\n';
         alert('From linklocation_onapply on observable\'s event function, data:\n'+attrs);
      }
   );
});
//16. register observers on widget mycompany.linkLocation
$("div.content").on({
   //an observer to a custom event mycompany.linkLocation.customevent
   "mycompany.linkLocation.customevent": function(evt, data){
      var attrs='';
      for(prop in data)
         attrs+=prop+': '+data[prop]+'\n';
      alert('From mycompany.linkLocation.customevent event on div.content event function, data:\n'+attrs);
   },
   //an observer to a custom event linklocation_onapply
   "linklocation_onapply": function(evt, data){
      var attrs='';
      for(prop in data)
         attrs+=prop+': '+data[prop]+'\n';
      alert('From linklocation_onapply event on div.content event function, data:\n'+attrs);
   },
   //an observer to a custom event linklocation_onuserapply
   "linklocation_onuserapply": function(evt, data){
      var attrs='';
      for(prop in data)
         attrs+=prop+': '+data[prop]+'\n';
      alert('From linklocation_onuserapply event on div.content event function, data:\n'+attrs);
   }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```